# Ruby/Rails: accessing a variable inside a .each on my instance variable array causing Ruby interpreter to crash

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm, ruby-1.9.2

I've written a mixin (based on something I read in a blog) that seems to be causing a problem

Here is a link to the project: http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/263759/onlinescheduler.zip (or send me an email: aaron.a.ashworth@gmail.com and I'll email it) and I've stripped as much out as I can for it to still cause the problem. The key files to look at are:

```
/lib/user_role.rb (near line 11)
/app/views/customers/index.html.erb (near line 16)
/app/controllers/customers_controller.rb (near line 47)
```

I'll layout the important stuff here as well:

`/lib/user_role.rb:`

```
module UserRole
    def self.included(base)
      base.has_one :user, :as => :user_role, :autosave => true
      base.validate :user_must_be_valid
      base.alias_method_chain :user, :autobuild
      base.extend ClassMethods
      base.define_user_accessors
    end

    def user_with_autobuild
      user_without_autobuild || build_user
    end

    def method_missing(meth, *args, &blk)
      user.send(meth, *args, &blk)
    rescue NoMethodError
      super
    end

    module ClassMethods
      def define_user_accessors
        all_attributes = User.content_columns.map(&:name) + ["password", "password_confirmation"]
        ignored_attributes = ["created_at", "updated_at", "user_role_type"]
        attributes_to_delegate = all_attributes - ignored_attributes
        attributes_to_delegate.each do |attrib|
          class_eval <<-RUBY
            def #{attrib}
              user.#{attrib}
            end

            def #{attrib}=(value)
              self.user.#{attrib} = value
            end

            def #{attrib}?
              self.user.#{attrib}?
            end
          RUBY
        end
      end
    end

  protected
    def user_must_be_valid
      Logger.new(STDOUT).info('calling user_must_be_valid')
      unless user.valid?
        user.errors.each do |attr, message|
          errors.add(attr, message)
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

`app/views/customers/index.html.erb:`

```
...
<% @customers.each do |customer| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= customer.account_id %></td>
...
```

accessing `customer` at all causes the problem. I can do anything to `@customers`
but as soon as I try to access `customer....` or even `@customers[0]....` I get a problem.

**Steps to produce**

1) After unzipping the file, go into the root directory in terminal and run these commands:

```
bundle install
bundle exec rake db:drop
bundle exec rake db:migrate
rails s
```

2) Open your browser to `localhost:3000/customers` and click `New Customer`

3) Fill in the form you see like so:

```
Account: 3
First Name: First
Last Name: Last
Email: first.last@domain.com
Password: 1234
Password confirmation: 1234
```

4) Click the `Create Customer` button.

**Expected Behavior**

You should be redirected to `localhost:3000/customers/1`

**Current Behaviour**

The webserver crashes as you get the following message:

```
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x17b356) [0x7fef4a97e356]
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x1713ee) [0x7fef4a9743ee]
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x177243) [0x7fef4a97a243]
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_vm_invoke_proc+0x9f) [0x7fef4a97b08f]
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x17b644) [0x7fef4a97e644]
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x1713ee) [0x7fef4a9743ee]
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x177243) [0x7fef4a97a243]
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x1784f4) [0x7fef4a97b4f4]
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x178cb5) [0x7fef4a97bcb5]
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x17b50d) [0x7fef4a97e50d]
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x1713ee) [0x7fef4a9743ee]

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
```

Rerunning the webserver and going to `localhost:3000/customers` sometimes gives you a different error. A segmentation fault and it complains about `/lib/user_role.rb:11`

**Environment**

```
Ruby 1.9.2-p290
Rails 3.0.9
RVM 1.8.1
Ubuntu 11.04
```

**Edit**

Something to note: If you try working the same code that bombs in console it seems fine. Example:

```
(After entering rails c)
@customers = Customer.all
@customers.each do |customer|
  p customer.account_id
end
# this doesn't cause an error or crash.

@customer[0].first_name
=> "First"
```

Comment: I will be adding bounty to this post as soon as that is made available. I know I'm asking a lot out of the community here but I don't have any RUGs in my area or anyone I know personally with any ruby experience. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using OS/X Lion and compiled Ruby after upgrading to Lion? In such case it might be what's causing the issue (if that's in fact your problem, I will post links on how to solve it).

Comment: Also, I've tried downloading your sample code to see if it works on my machine, but couldn't get the link email from your host. Can you post it somewhere else that we can just download it from? Thanks

Comment: Maybe your machine has memory problems? I doubt, but it may be worth checking _(memtest?)_, just for being sure.

Comment: @arikfi, I'm using Ubuntu 11.04. If you are ok with sending me an email (don't post yours for your anonymity but mine is: aaron.a.ashworth@gmail.com) I will email it to you. I wish you could attach files to SO posts and meta work-a-around was that horrible download site.

Comment: @Arsen7, I don't think its a memory issue. I have gobs of ram and not much running while I'm running the application.

Comment: I was talking about damaged memory, not about lack of it. But as I said, I doubt that it's really the case, because it would be expectable that other programs also should fail sometimes.

Comment: @Arsen7. Got it. That is extremely unlikely because this computer is about a month old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove:

```
def method_missing(meth, *args, &blk)
  customer.send(meth, *args, &blk)
rescue NoMethodError
  super
end
```

and

```
def method_missing(meth, *args, &blk)
  user.send(meth, *args, &blk)
rescue NoMethodError
  super
end
```

from the x_role files in your lib directory, it should work fine. On a side note look into inherited resource for your controllers and simple form for your forms.

Comment: Matthew, what would immediately solve my issues is a gem that lets me have a `User` model that allows for a `Customer` model to derive from `User` **WITHOUT** putting `User` and `Customer` in the same table (i.e. STI) but still being able to access something like `@customer.login` instead of `@customer.user.login`.

Comment: Matthew, I think this solved my problem. I'm going to do some more testing this weekend but I think this is what fixed my issue.

Comment: You could put the shared code into a module then just include the module into both your customer and user models

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about making a gem when you could add acts_as_bleh in a model and it would automatically hook it up. Matt, did you receive the bounty? It was removed from my rep but it looks like your rep didn't go up by 200.

Comment: @DJTripleThreat odd seems that I didn't, it's probably a bug